# How to update correctly a table?

Tags: sql, node.js

I try to update a table.

I do  a first request to get all rows then I update this table with same data but passwords are crypted before update.

```
'use strict';
var sql = require('./db.js');
var crypto = require('crypto');
var Crypt = require('./encryption.js');
//Support object constructor
var Login = function(login){
        this.login = login.login;
        this.password = login.password;
};

sql.query("SELECT * FROM login WHERE Password IS NOT NULL OR Password != ''", function(err,res) {
        if (err) {
                console.log(err);
        }
        else {
                console.log(res.length);
                for (var i = 0; i < res.length ; i++) {
                        //console.log(res[i].Password);
                        //if (res[i].Password != '' ){
                        sql.query("UPDATE login SET Password = ? where id=?", [Crypt.encrypt(res[i].Password), i], fu
                                if (err){
                                        console.log(err);
                                }else {
                                        console.log(res2, 'ok');
                                }
                        }) //}
                }
        }
})
```

When I do update only some rows are updatted but not all. I want to do it on all rows.

Comment: any idea to my problem ?

Answer (score 0):

the mistake was in the query. I was using the iterator as id but ids aren't orderded in the database. It was res[i].id instead of i in the query parameter